# Reading from file into Structure in C

Tags: c, midi, audio-player

I'm new to programming in C, doing some work on a MIDI recording program that plays back the notes, and can't seem to get the program to read from the file into my structure array.

Here's the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int noteNumber;
    int vel;
    int oscillatorNumber;
    float freq;
} oneNote;
```

And here's the code to read the notes in:

```
oneNote notes[2000];

for (count = 0; count < fileSize; count++)
{
    fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d %d\n", &notes[count].noteNumber,
                                      &notes[count].vel,
                                      &notes[count].oscillatorNumber);

    notes[count].freq = ntof(notes[count].noteNumber);
}
```

Code where file is opened:

```
filePointer = fopen("noteRecordFile.txt", "r");

if (filePointer == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file\n");
}
else
{
    printf("File opened\n");

    fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(filePointer);
}
```

Just doesn't store the and of the data in the structure, as can be seen here:

[Image of debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNFT5.png)

First few lines of noteRecordFile.txt:

```
48 108 0
50 108 0
52 100 0
```

Comment: Please provide the portion of code where you open the file too

Comment: I have done now, when I run the program it says the file is opened

Comment: Please provide the first few lines of the `noteRecordFile.txt` file.

Comment: I've edited it into the post

Comment: Why do you use `fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_END);`? By default, the file should be open at the begging, not the end. To be sure, you can use `fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_SET);`

Comment: You already have reached the end of the file in the quest to determine its length. Did you forget to do `fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_SET)` to come back to beginning of the file?

Comment: Oh! Thank you, this was exactly the problem.

Comment: @HarryJordan : You might consider adding `while(fgetc (filepointer)!='\n') continue;` after the fscanf line. Just to waste the buffer at the end of each line. This will save you from unintentional  spaces at the end of each line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

Remove following 2 lines, because it puts the file pointer to the end of the file and we want to start the reading at the start of the file, and `ftell` will give you the number of bytes in the file and not the number of lines.

```
fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell(filePointer);
```

Then you need this:

```
  FILE *filePointer = fopen("noteRecordFile.txt", "r");

  if (filePointer == NULL)
  {
      printf("Error opening file\n");
      exit(1);   // <<< abort program if file could not be opened
  }
  else
  {
      printf("File opened\n");
  }

  int count = 0;
  do
  {
      fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d %d", &notes[count].noteNumber,
                                        &notes[count].vel,
                                        &notes[count].oscillatorNumber);

      notes[count].freq = ntof(notes[count].noteNumber);
      count++;
  }
  while (!feof(filePointer));  // <<< read until end of file is reached
  ...
```

We cannot know the number of lines the file contains without reading the whole file, so we use a different approach: we just read until the end of the file is reached.

You still need to add a check, because if the file contains more than 2000 lines, you will run into trouble. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

It won't because you reached the end of the file on the line:

```
fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_END);
```

you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file:

```
fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_SET)
```

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the problem

Comment: @HarryJordan: that's just _one_ problem. Read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your file format ? 
As i see, you read the header too as a normal data line...

Try reading this, maybe it'll help you.

[MIDI](http://valentin.dasdeck.com/midi/midifile.htm)

You can try openning the file as binary, i remember it fixed an issue i had on some sound files...!

Do you have any error/warning during compilation and execution ?

Comment: The file format was fine, sjsam had the answer, but thank you